# VBA SQL ? Pushing email attachments to SQL BLOB field

Tags: sql, vba, blob

I am trying to figure out the way to push mailitem.attachments to a SQL BLOB field. I think i need to do this as a stream or binary but I am not 100% sure?

```
Public Sub BLOB(avMailitem As Variant)

    Dim gobjApp                             As Object
    Dim gobjOriginalWorkItem                As Object
    Dim gcnnSqlServerConnection             As ADODB.Connection
    Dim grsBLOB                             As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim vCPDID                              As Variant
    Dim vAttach                             As Variant
    Dim i                                   As Integer
    Dim iTotal                              As Integer

    Set gcnnSqlServerConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    gcnnSqlServerConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb; Server=XXXXXXXXXX; Database=XXXXXX; uid=XXX; pwd=XXX; "
    gcnnSqlServerConnection.Open
    Set grsBLOB = New ADODB.Recordset

    vSql = "dbo.BLOB"
    grsBLOB.Open vSql, gcnnSqlServerConnection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

    vCPDID = avMailitem.UserProperties.Add("CPDId", olText, True).Value
    iTotal = avMailitem.Attachments.Count

    i = 1
    For i = 1 To iTotal

        Set vAttach = avMailitem.Attachments(i)

        With grsBLOB

            .AddNew
            .Fields("CPDID") = vCPDID
            .Fields("Attachments") = vAttach
            .Update
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```